# Template fragment cache sometimes not loading in my django project?

Tags: python, django, caching, django-templates, memcached

So my `store_navbar` sometimes loads sometimes doesn't. 
I'm using django 1.7. 
I use fragment cache to load categories in my `navbar`.

```
{% load cache %}
{% cache CACHE_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT store_navbar store.id %}
{% include template_root|add:"navbar/categories.html" %}
{% endcache %}
```

My cache timeout variable is:

```
CACHE_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 86400
```

Comment: You tagged this with `memcached` - can you confirm that you're cache backend isn't accidentally set to Local-memory caching? In this case for every restart the cache would be cleared.

Comment: It's not in local-memory, it happens just once a day and we have to clear the cache for it to appear again.

Comment: "it doesnt load" means the fragement stays empty?

Comment: Yes, it just doesn't appear sometimes like once a day until the cache is cleared.

Comment: Just to clarify, the value in memcached is an empty string once in a while instead of expected HTML? If so, can you rule out any "swallowed" exceptions that might be triggered in the template?